# What should the second parameter be for the Kaiser's filter?

Tags: matlab, filtering, signal-processing

I have this given.

The noisy signal was sampled at 44100 Hz.
Passband edge: 2500 Hz.
Stopband edge: 4000 Hz.
Maximum gain in the passband Gpbmax: 40 dB.
Minimum gain in the passband Gpbmin: 37 dB.
Maximum gain in the stopband Gsbmax: −55 dB.

And i have to filter it using Kaiser (low pass filter), however, I did not understand what to place in the second parameter ([1 0]), and if the other parameters are correct ? 
I am receiving an n = -36. I do not know what to do

My code:

```
% Design Kaiser Filter
Fs = 44100;          % Sampling Frequency (Hz)
Fcuts = [2500 4000]; % cutoff Frequency
pass = [3 55];       % passband 

% Use kaiserord to get the minimum order of the filter
[n,Wn,beta,ftype] = kaiserord(Fcuts, [1 0], pass, Fs);
```

The same question goes for Parks-McClellan 
[N,Fo,Ao,W] = firpmord(F,A,DEV,Fs)
is it the same ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The passband and stopband deviations cannot be given in dB.

```
pass = [3 55];       % passband
```

It must be given in terms of filter gains.

```
doc kaiserord
```

says

> dev is a vector the same size as a that specifies the maximum allowable error or deviation between the frequency response of the output filter and its desired amplitude, for each band. The entries in dev specify the passband ripple and the stopband attenuation. **You specify each entry in dev as a positive number, representing absolute filter gain (not in decibels).**

Answer (score 0):

Interesting, have you tried to [google](https://www.google.se/?gws_rd=ssl) the question. I googled "kaiser matlab" and got up `kaiser`on the first hit and `kaiserord` on the second.

The documentation clearly stated that `Fcuts` is the frequency bands and the second input `a` is the amplitude of the the frequencies in `Fcuts`. So what you states is that the magnitude is 1 for Fcuts(1) and 0 (or close to) for Fcuts(2).

Comment: @achehab well yes, but you cannot say that my answer did not answer the top question. However, for the rest, no it is not correct. You set the passband edge gain to 0 dB but the specification is Gpbmin: 37 dB You do also need to specify another point earlier to fulfill the requirement Gpbmax: 40 dB (0 Hz maybe?) and the parameter pass must be in absolute coordinates as the rest. You are also far to tough with -inf db for the stopband edge. -55 dB (in absolute coordinates) is enough